# Linewise history

Tags: undo-redo

We can use the `u`, `<C-R>` to undo/redo in Vim and it provides a lot of features to manage the undo tree.

But sometimes, I make a change (let say on line 1) and I go do some other changes on another line.

When I come back to line 1, I may think that the previous value of this line was better.

My current workflow is:

- undo until I get the value back
- yank the line
- redo until the top of the undo tree
- replace the line.

I think this clearly can be improved, but do you know if there is a vim feature that provide an history of changes for each line?

Comment: For the 1st step, you can use `:changes` - the most recent value on the 2nd column that matches the line number you want to redo has a change number (1st column) associated with it, that can be used as a count to `g;` (add one to that count number).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are in dire need of https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim. Watch a screencast about it at http://screenr.com/M9l

Comment: I use undotree, but I've used Gundo in the past, and I don't remember it having this feature (that is, the linewise history).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree). Its pure vimscript and uses vim's undo-tree feature added in 7.0

Comment: I use it, and I've used Gundo in the past, and I don't remember any of them having this feature (that is, the linewise history).

Comment: No, neither undotree nor gundo has linewise history. I've looked in the past for a plugin to do this without results. The benifit is you can much more easily perform your current workflow...same workflow I use.